# How to get user email address from ASP.NET MVC Default Membership Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can get the user name as `User.Identity.Name`. How can I get a user's email address because it must be stored (there is a textbox for it in the registration form)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    someLabel.Text = Membership.GetUser().Email;
}
```

There are a lot of useful user properties resulting from the [`Membership.GetUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcxcb339.aspx) function. It returns an object of type [`MembershipUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx).

Comment: I added a custom DOB field in the user table, how can I get that?

Answer (score 6):

```
protected string GetEmailAddress()
{
    MembershipUser currUser = null;
    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
    {   
        currUser = Membership.GetUser(true);
        return currUser.Email; 
    }   
    return currUser.Email;
}
```

Comment: Like the approach, although your code snippet would actually throw a null reference exception if HttpContext.Current.User == null. Probably not the exact exception type you'd want to throw here.

Answer (score 2):

On MVC5, you can use the UserManager for that, like this:

```
string UserEmail = await UserManager.GetEmailAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Comment: For  those who don't have `UserManager` instantiated already this code is handy: `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<YourNamespace.ApplicationUserManager>()`

Answer (score 0):

or if the information is coming from outside the page you can do like this.

```
 string userName = Request.QueryString["username"];

     TextBoxUserID.Text = Membership.GetUser(userName).Email;
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to include a short explanation on how your code addresses the issue even if it is pretty self explanatory :P