# How to get user profile data from ASP.NET MVC custom IdentityUser Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

With the help of [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx), I have added a custom profile property **OfficeKey** to ApplicationUser class (in IdentityModels.cs file):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
      public int OfficeKey { get; set; }

      //remaining code here
}
```

I can get user name like this:

```
   User.Identity.Name
```

> *How do I get custom user data **OfficeKey**?*

I have tried these:

[How to get Identity User Data from Asp.net mvc Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288879/how-to-get-identity-user-data-from-asp-net-mvc-model)

[How to get user email address from ASP.NET MVC Default Mempership Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761682/how-to-get-user-email-address-from-asp-net-mvc-default-mempership-model)

**NB:** It is an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application with MySQL membership provider.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you configure the `UserManager` with the `ApplicationUser` it will return the user with the information as follows:

```
 // Create manager
 var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
    new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(
        new ApplicationDbContext()))

// Find user
var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

The `OfficeKey` will be available in the user.