# How to get user in ASP.NET Identity provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, asp.net-identity

### With the help of ASP.NET membership provider:

We can get a **logged in** user by [configuring the UserManager with the ApplicationUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216915/how-to-get-user-profile-data-from-asp-net-mvc-custom-identityuser-model/30217188#30217188)

> So far so good for getting logged in user data!

---

**Problem:**

Is there a way to get user(s) who are **not logged in**?

Maybe by some alternative for `User.Identity.GetUserId()` method - which works for logged in users?

By passing user number or username or so?

---

**Aim:** This is needed for different situations such as:

- Getting a user with username X
- To show a list of users having usernames starting with an alphabet
- Users having X location
- etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Identity 2.0+ then it [exposes an IQueryable interface to the user store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613208%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). You can use this to do almost everyhting you asked about:

```
UserManager.Users.Where(w => w.Location == "Mars").ToList();
```

You can use any kind of LINQ fanciness there. You may also just hit the DB table directly as you do in other controllers. If using EF, something like:

```
db.AspNetUsers.Where(w => w.Username == "Bob").AsEnumerable();
```